# Handling null dictionary deserialization

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

I'm deserializing an object using JsonConvert in c# and for a field on in my object, I tried to deserialize a `Dictionary<int,string>`, so I've used the attribute up on the field in my class as follows:

```
[JsonProperty("variablephysicalproperties", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public Dictionary<int,string> VariablePhysicalProperties { get; set; }
```

So the deserialization works perfectly when the value of that property is for example:

```
"variablephysicalproperties":{"1":"Sph\u00e8re (SPH)"}
```

But when there is no value in it as:

```
"variablephysicalproperties":[]
```

It doesn't work, I've got a deserialization error. As shown above I've tried the 
`NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` but still doesn't work

Could somebody help me with that ?

Comment: Why do you have `[]` in the first place? That's an empty array, not an empty object (which would be `{}`). And neither `[]` nor `{}` is `null`.

Comment: It's a good question that I've asked to the api master...

Comment: By setting  **NullValueHandling.Ignore** you inform deserializer that *"variablephysicalproperties":[]* should`t be in json file. And it would be better if you show exception details as well.

Comment: How is the Json you are using created?

Comment: Json.NET [expects a dictionary to be an object or `null`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm), so will throw an exception if it encounters an array instead. You might use the `JsonGenericDictionaryOrArrayConverter` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451990/newtonsoft-json-deserialize-dictionary-as-key-value-list-from-datacontractjsonse/28633769#28633769) to chew through the empty array.