# Deserialize - String JSON to List of Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have this string:

```
string json = "[[{"Key":"COL1","Value":"8404"},{"Key":"LIN1","Value":"972"},{"Key":"CAT","Value":"C"}],[{"Key":"COL1","Value":"8406"},{"Key":"LIN1","Value":"971"},{"Key":"CAT","Value":"A"}]]";
```

I have defined this type:

```
public class Table : List<Dictionary<string, string>> { }
```

How can I deserialize the string into the Table class?

So far I tried this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var values = ser.Deserialize<Table>(json);
```

But I get a length 0 variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: One thing to note about the dupe: the `{"Key":"COL1", "Value":"8404"}` will be deserialized as a `Dictionary<string, string>` with two entries (the first has a key of "Key" and a value of "COL1"). So, your specific JSON is actually representing an `List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`.

Comment: @zerkms the thing is how to deserialize into a derived/inherited class

Comment: If you are willing to switch to [tag:json.net], this becomes a duplicate of [Newtonsoft Json Deserialize Dictionary as Key/Value list from DataContractJsonSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633769/3744182).