# .NET Dictionary serialization/deserialization discrepancy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dictionary, .net-core

I have stumbled upon a discrepancy when transferring a `Dictionary` from a .NET Standard WCF web-service to a .NET Core 2.0 client (using Newtonsoft Json).

### Server-side

The service interface is the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISomeService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  SomeClass SomeWebMethod();
}
```

The server-side class is the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeClass
{
  [DataMember]
  public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

And this produces the following JSON response:

```
{
  "SomeDictionary": [
    {
      "Key": "some key",
      "Value": "some value"
    },
    {
      "Key": "some other key",
      "Value": "some other value"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Notice**: The WCF service serialized the `Dictionary` in a `Key` - `Value` fashion.

### Client-side

The client-side class is the following:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

So, both the server-side and the client-side classes are identical (except for the lack of attributes on the client-side).

However, the web-service call produces the following error:

> "DeserializeResponse" failed with
>   "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. **{"name":"value"}**) to
>   deserialize correctly.

**Notice**: the client expects the `Dictionary` to be delivered in a `name` - `value` fashion, which is clearly different than what the server sends - hence the error.

The deserialization is done "by-hand" with the following code snippet:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
```

As you can see, I don't have any attributes on the client-side class and use only the default options when performing the deserialization.

### Question

How can I unify the (de)serialization of the `Dictionary`? I can make changes in both the server-side or the client-side.

The only alternative I can think of is to completely ditch the `Dictionary` and make a `List` of a custom `Key` - `Value` class on both ends.

Comment: As far as I understand, your server returns you an XML response, which means that client needs to use XMLSerializer (instead of Json serializer) to deserialize content into dictionary

Comment: How are you making the call with the Newtonsoft serializer? The .NET framework's serializers are known to be somewhat idiosyncratic. I believe the JsonDataContractSerializer will serialize dictionaries as something like `[ { "key": "x", "value": "1" } ]` instead of the way everyone expects like `{ "x" : "1" }`.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451990/newtonsoft-json-deserialize-dictionary-as-key-value-list-from-datacontractjsonse) has an implementation of a Json.NET converter for this form of dictionary serialization.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan: the client receives JSON. The XML I pasted is from the log files. I have since edited my question and am now showing the actual JSON response that the client receives.

Comment: @mikez: I am using a one-liner to deserialize the JSON string: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json)`. I have also included this snipped in my question.

Comment: @alesc the discrepancy is in the *code*. You serialized an *object* of type Dictionary which contains *properties* named Key and Value. In any case, WCF is meant for *SOAP* messages, not JSON. Are you trying to use `Dictionary` as a "dynamic" object?

Comment: @alesc furthermore, JSON and SOAP don't mix. SOAP/XML can serialize objects just fine. It DOESN'T need pseudodynamic objects either - you specify what you return in the WSDL and XSD. With WCF, you create types and the XSD is created automatically. Clients **expect** you to fulfill that **contract**. You can return *anything* you want as long as you put it in the XSD. That means, you can return anything you want as long as you give it the proper type.

Comment: @alesc which is trivial - make your DTOs inherit from the same base object or interface and use that in your WCF service

Comment: @alesc BTW that's a design bug of the code. Even REST APIs have and *need* schemas. You have to tell the clients what to expect. That's why Swagger is used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: from the perspective of the code, I _do_ use the same DTOs (the `Dictionary` on both side). The only thing I can do, is to use a `List` of custom `Key`-`Value` class on both ends. This will definitely work, but I would rather look at other solutions before using this approach.

Comment: @alesc no you don't. You are using a dictionary instead of a DTO. And anyway, why are you generating *strings* by hand when WCF is responsible for serialization?

Comment: @alesc of course, an even better question would be "Why are you using WCF instead of Web API for *REST* in a *.NET Standard* library ?" WCF was *never* meant for REST APIs. The REST functionality was only a stopgap measure 10 years ago, until Web API's release

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: this is a legacy application so I don't have the option to change such things. It looks like there are not attributes that could rename the serialization schema of the `Dictionary`, so I will stop using it and rather use a custom class that I can fully control. Thank you for your input!