# Serialize/Deserialize complex Dictionary<ClassA><ClassB> by Newtonsoft JSON gives me errors while deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, nsjsonserialization

My JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Key": {
      "PatientName": "Hans Gerd",
      "Alter": 81,
      "Geschlecht": "M",
      "Zimmernummer": 1,
      "PatientenLiegeplatz": 0,
      "IsDummyData": false
    },
    "Value": {
      "Puls": 0,
      "Temperatur": 0.0,
      "Systole": 0,
      "Diastole": 0,
      "DictationText": "",
      "Timestamp": "2021.05.24 12:31:06"
    }
  }
]
```

Serialization:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveObj.CareRoutineDataDictionary.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);
```

How to Deserialize it? I have tried so much and it doesn't work.
Common error Messages:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

If I try to do:

```
Dictionary<BasicPatientData, CareRoutineData> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<BasicPatientData, CareRoutineData>>(File.ReadAllText(SaveFilePath));
```

I get an error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[BasicPatientData,CareRoutineData]'
> because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
> deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
> JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
> an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
> ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
> array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON array.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear what all your types are, also why are you doing `ToArray` when you serialise?

Comment: The toArray is neccessary otherwise the Keys are not serialized, i only get the second of the Dictionary then.

Comment: That isn't true, it will still give you the keys.

Comment: You have a dictionary with **complex keys** that has been serialized as an array.  You need to deserialize that as a `List<KeyValuePair<BasicPatientData, CareRoutineData>>` and then convert to a dictionary.  See [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873/3744182).  Or you could use one of the `JsonConverter` implementations from [Newtonsoft Json Deserialize Dictionary as Key/Value list from DataContractJsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28451990/3744182).  In fact this looks to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: `CustomDictionaryConverter<BasicPatientData, CareRoutineData>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310390/3744182) to [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873/3744182) looks like it might the easiest and most general solution.